# Offset lines to find self intersection lines

Tags: contour, offset, parallel-lines

I've been trying, with no success, to create of negative offset from line shapefiles (contour lines, actually). My objective is, with the x offset I define, to use the topology rules to identify the lines that self-intersect. I haven't found anything on ArcGIS that might help. With QGIS tools, I tried "offset lines" but if the lines eventually intersect, that output changes shape to avoid those situations.

[image: Original line and produced results with offsetlines]

[image: Original line and intended result]

Any solutions or ideas outside of what I'm trying?

Comment: What you want is topologically invalid, so you should expect it to be difficult to obtain.  The good news is that it's easy to make a broken geometry on your own with just basic trigonometry.

Comment: Why do you want to identify the offset lines that intersect, what is your ultimate goal

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to cut the initial line in two. Use [Split Feature](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features) tool to cut the line at two positions where the lines don't come close (to the left and right, in our case). Then use QGIS expressions with `offset_curve( $geometry, [distance])` to create the line you want.

*The initial line in black and red (to show the two features), the line created with the expression in blue. Red arrows show the two spots where the line was split in two:*
[image]

**Variant**

Use the following expression (adapting the the distance-values in line 3) to generate several lines at once:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (50, 600, 50),
        offset_curve( $geometry, @element)
    )
)
```

[image]